# Why does bundler think it needs a specific version when the gemspec specifies a pessimistic constraint?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

My gemspec clearly requires `active_support ~> 3.0`, but bundler is failing to `bundle install` saying that my gem requires `active_support = 3.0`. WTF bundler? Can anyone explain this?

```
$ gem install code_filter
Successfully installed activesupport-3.0.0
Successfully installed active_support-3.0.0
Successfully installed code_filter-0.1.1
```

---

```
$ gem dependency code_filter
Gem code_filter-0.1.1
  active_support (~> 3.0, runtime)
```

---

```
$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.......
Fetching gem metadata from http://192.168.10.22/...
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from http://192.168.10.22/..
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    code_filter (= 0.1.1) ruby depends on
      activesupport (= 3.0.0) ruby

    json_builder (~> 3.1) ruby depends on
      activesupport (3.0.20)
```

Comment: What's the deal with `activesupport` and `active_support`? It seems you depend on on `active_support`, but Bundler is looking for `activesupport`?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: I don't quite remember unfortunately. But I do think @bheeshmar was right that there was something odd with the activesupport and active_support different spelling. like, they are actually two different gems and one depends on the other, or something...

Comment: They renamed the gem – it used to be named `active_support`, but the latest version there is 3.0.0: https://rubygems.org/gems/active_support The latest version of `activesupport` at the time of writing is 4.2.0: https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport You want the latter in newer projects.