# "Bundler could not find compatible versions" even though gemspec has ">=" that should allow compatibility

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I'm trying to upgrade a Rails 3 app to Rails 4.

My Gemfile includes

```
gem 'rails', '>= 4'
gem 'active_shipping', github: 'barsoom/active_shipping'
```

When I do `bundle update rails active_shipping activesupport`, I get this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activesupport":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (>= 4) ruby depends on
      activesupport (= 4.0.0) ruby

    active_shipping (>= 0) ruby depends on
      activesupport (3.2.0)
```

But [the gemspec for this fork of active_shipping](https://github.com/barsoom/active_shipping/blob/master/active_shipping.gemspec#L19) says `s.add_dependency('activesupport', '>= 3.2', '< 5.0.0')`.

My impression is that this should be compatible with the "= 4.0.0" dependency in `activesupport`.

I had a similar situation with another dependency – when I removed the ">= 3.2.8" condition in *that* dependency, so it didn't mention an `activesupport` version at all, the error went away.

Obviously I have a mistaken assumption somewhere. Why wouldn't ">= 3.2" or ">= 3.2.8" be compatible with "= 4.0.0"?

Going by the error message ("depends on activesupport (3.2.0)"), Bundler for some reason interprets the `'>= 3.2', '< 5.0.0'` as "3.2.0". But why?

Comment: If you have your `Gemfile.lock` under source control and do a `bundle update` (without specifying any gems) does that avoid the conflict? Then you could copy back the lines from SC that you don't want to update.

Comment: @Coenwulf Hm, I'll give that a shot. Thank you. We have a lot of gems though, so the copying back might be a bit of effort, but better than being entirely blocked for sure.

Comment: I tried adding `gem 'activesupport', '>= 4'` to my own Gemfile, on the assumption that any explicit declarations there would prevent Bundler from making poor decisions later. It might actually have worked – I still get version compatibility errors, but now it's for other gems than `active_shipping`.

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14697648/why-does-bundler-think-it-needs-a-specific-version-when-the-gemspec-specifies-a?rq=1 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27253373/why-is-bundler-insisting-on-an-exact-gem-version-number-when-the-gemspec-states?rq=1

Comment: Did you try to `bundle update` all gems, not just the two you mentioned? You might miss other shared dependency, when you dictate bundler to update only a small subset.

Comment: @spickermann Haven't tried that yet since we have a lot of gems and I don't dare update some of the more crucial ones just like that. But doing it temporarily and then restoring some, like Coenwulf suggested, is my plan B. But wouldn't Bundler's error message point to the other dependency if that was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I added

```
gem 'activesupport', '>= 4'
```

to my own `Gemfile` (in my Rails app), on the assumption that any explicit declarations there would prevent Bundler from making poor decisions later.

It seemed to do the trick. I got some other conflicts with other gems later, but then resolved them, and now the updating works.